# Momentarily use Angular loader even when views are cached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loader, ng-show, ng-hide

I've successfully set up a full-page loading indicator in Angular following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMxQHmvQ1pA) method. It uses ng-hide/ng-show, which I fade in and out using CSS. Here's my code:

**The HTML bit:**

```
<div ng-show="loading" class="loader">Loading</div>
```

**The CSS bit:**

```
.loader {
    transition: 0.25s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.ng-hide-add {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**The Angular bit:**

```
myApp.controller('appController', function($scope, $route, $rootScope) {
    $scope.$on('LOAD',function(){$scope.loading=true});
    $scope.$on('UNLOAD',function(){$scope.loading=false});
});

myApp.controller('pageController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$emit('LOAD')
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.$emit('UNLOAD');
    });
});
```

It looks nice on fresh page loads, but once you've cached pages in the app and navigate back to those pages you miss out on the fading page transitions, as the loader is unnecessary.

How can I ensure that the loader will display for at least 500ms if the page is cached and would otherwise not show the loader?

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically give a delay for the indicator of the animation. For example changing the `loading` scope variable to false after a time delay might be a straight approach;

```
myApp.controller('appController', function($scope, $route, $rootScope) {
    $scope.$on('LOAD',function(){$scope.loading=true});
    $scope.$on('UNLOAD',function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.loading = false;
      }, 500);
    });
});
```

This way, load action will do the same thing as it was doing, and "unload" action will have a 500ms delay.

---

**BUT**, in the case of loading an uncached page will cause your app to delay your animation +500ms every time, what this mean is, lets say your page draw takes 200ms and you are adding 500ms to that, causing a 700ms delay in total.

If this is a big problem for you, I would advise you to create a timer when the page load animation starts then remove the load time from your 500ms wait time when the unload action will be happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made a Plunker using your example. It doesn't appear to ensure that the loader will show beyond the initial view: https://embed.plnkr.co/HqwjgsAsTdi46xYsPxoo/ — Am I missing something?